# What is this format

Tags: php

what is this format and how to decode it to plain json?

```
a:24:{s:12:"webhook_data";a:41:{s:2:"id";i:4582988775555;s:8:"order_id";
```

It is way longer so I am pasting only little sample of it. There are such a:24 and any other symbols everywhere.

Comment: It looks like the [PHP Serialization Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP_serialization_format), which can be unserialized using the [unserialize function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php). It probably (not guaranteed) can be converted to JSON using `json_encode(unserialize($your_data));`

Comment: That is wordpress [serialized data](https://wpengine.com/support/wordpress-serialized-data/)

Comment: @rzlvmp it's available in any PHP program, not just wordpress